# Open Sets Definitions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, definition

I took a real analysis course in my second semester. We studied about metric spaces from baby Rudin. In that it was clearly defined that w.r.t Metric Spaces that a set is open if for every point inside it we can find a neighborhood of that point which lies completely inside that set.

Now in my fourth semester, I am taking a course in Introductory Topology. We are following Munkres. In the book, its given that if a subset  $U$ belongs to a topology of a set $X$, then $U$ is open in $X$.

I am really confused between the two as they are being used interchangeably. Can anybody please explain whether are the both definitions equivalent or not?

Comment: For metric space open sets, prove that the entire space and the empty set are open sets for any metric space. Given a collection of open sets, prove that the union of those sets is open. Finally, prove that the intersection of two open sets is open. Once you do that, revisit the definition of a topology. Does it look familiar?

Comment: I'm sure someone else will expand on this a lot more, but until then I'll mention that technically the notions are different since they don't even apply to the same type of mathematical object. However, it turns out that every metric space can be viewed as a topological space (use the metric space's open sets for the topology; of course, one needs to prove the metric space's open sets satisfy the axioms for a topology; note that the converse is not true), and when this identification is made, then the two collections of open sets are equal.

Comment: They are equivalent. The notion of a topology is an abstraction of a metric space topology. I always loved Munkres' book on Topology but his presentation hides the thinking behind topology. Nobody wrote down the axioms for a topology and later figured out metric spaces were topological spaces. Like all abstractions, we start from the concrete and focus on the properties that characterize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a metric space, a set is open if it is a member of the (implicit) topology consisting of all sets described via the neighborhoods as you do. The topology (as a set of open sets) is not mentioned explicitly, but it is there.

The equivalent notion in an arbitrary topological space is that of a topology generated by a basis: a basis is a set of elements of the topology such that given any element $U$ of the topology and any $x\in U$, there exists a $B$ in the basis such that $x\in B\subseteq U$. The given basis for a metric space is the set of all open balls.

Answer (score 1):

Studying metric spaces one quickly realizes the fundamental role played by the open sets (as defined in the original post).

This is attested by results showing that several other important notions may be phrased in terms of open sets alone (not involving the metric).

For example: a function is **continuous** iff the inverse image of every **open** set is open; a sequence **converges** to a point $a$ iff every **open** set containing $a$ eventually contains all points of the sequence.

This leads one to suspect that the metric is disposable, that is, if one knows which sets are open and nothing else, one may develop large parts of the theory unhindered.

This is the idea behind the definition of a Topology, where, ignoring any metric, one postulates a collection of sets to call the open sets.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I really relate with it now. I used to think while studying metric spaces, everything is the magic of neighborhoods and open sets. I realise now well.